The problem requires sorting a string composed of both lowercase and uppercase letters
Take a string composed of both lowercase and uppercase letters and sort it in such a manner that the uppercase and lowercase letters come alternately but in a sorted way. 
Enter the String: HelLoWoRld
Sample Output:
The Sorted String is: HdLeRlWloo
My solution was
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the String: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        String sortedString = sortString(input);
        System.out.println("The Sorted String is: " + sortedString);
    }

    public static String sortString(String str) {
        StringBuilder sorted = new StringBuilder();

        // Separate lowercase and uppercase letters
        StringBuilder lower = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder upper = new StringBuilder();
        for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
                lower.append(ch);
            } else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                upper.append(ch);
            }
        }

        // Sort the lowercase and uppercase letters
        char[] lowerChars = lower.toString().toCharArray();
        char[] upperChars = upper.toString().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(lowerChars);
        Arrays.sort(upperChars);

        // Merge the sorted lowercase and uppercase letters alternately
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < lowerChars.length || j < upperChars.length) {
            if (i < lowerChars.length) {
                sorted.append(lowerChars[i++]);
            }
            if (j < upperChars.length) {
                sorted.append(upperChars[j++]);
            }
        }

        return sorted.toString();
    }
}

However I'm not getting all text cases right


Proposed grade: 37.50 / 100
Result Description
Failed tests
Test 2: string sort testcase2
Test 3: string sort testcase1
Test 4: string sort testcase4
Test 5: string sort testcase5
Test 6: string sort testcase6
Test 1: string sort testcase3
Summary of tests 
*Note: All the test cases might not have same weightage
+------------------------------+
|  8 tests run/ 3 tests passed |
+------------------------------+

What should be the answer for this program or is my approach is completely wrong?

Did you try with the provided test case? It seems like you'll append a lowercase character first

You need to explicitly show input and expected output.  Your question does not indicate whether your output is expected or what you are getting.

@OneCricketeer's comment was correct.  Change your last while loop to start appending the upper case letters first.
while (i < lowerChars.length || j < upperChars.length) {
    if (j < upperChars.length) {
         sorted.append(upperChars[j++]);
    }
    if (i < lowerChars.length) {
         sorted.append(lowerChars[i++]);
    }
}

Since you are working with letters, if it isn't lower case, it must be upper case so you don't need a separate test. So when you divide the string into upper and lower case strings just do:
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
     if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
          lower.append(ch);
     } else {
          upper.append(ch);
     }
}

Note that some case tests (e.g. for digits) return false in both cases. But that shouldn't apply here unless you want to exclude non-letters which wasn't mentioned in your question.

In your solution, there are two problems:

Space: lower/lowerChars and upper/upperChars are duplicated
Time: lower.toString().toCharArray() and upper.toString().toCharArray() add more extra time for your solution

We can do better (use a big amount of data to see the difference).
The optimozed solution:
public String sort(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    int n = chars.length;

    int lowercaseIndex = 0;
    int uppercaseIndex = n - 1;
    while (lowercaseIndex <= uppercaseIndex) {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(chars[lowercaseIndex])) {
            lowercaseIndex++;
        } else if (Character.isUpperCase(chars[uppercaseIndex])) {
            uppercaseIndex--;
        } else {
            swap(chars, lowercaseIndex, uppercaseIndex);
            lowercaseIndex++;
            uppercaseIndex--;
        }
    }

    // Sort the separated lowercase and uppercase letters in place
    Arrays.sort(chars, 0, lowercaseIndex);
    Arrays.sort(chars, lowercaseIndex, n);

    // Merge sorted lowercase and uppercase letters alternately in place
    StringBuilder sortedString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, j = lowercaseIndex; i < lowercaseIndex || j < n; i++, j++) {
        if (i < lowercaseIndex) {
            sortedString.append(chars[i]);
        }
        if (j < n) {
            sortedString.append(chars[j]);
        }
    }

    return sortedString.toString();
}

private static void swap(char[] chars, int i, int j) {
    char temp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[j];
    chars[j] = temp;
}


Your method is only a little bit more efficient for huge strings (100_000) characters. But that doesn't matter since it fails for many examples, even small ones as short as 10 characters. Try NGmGafjTwr

Problem fixed. Logically, there is no difference between mine and the question solution. So they should have the same result for every test case.
